# Remove and create IIS 6 site using Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis-6

I'm Trying to develope a powershell  script to create our websites from the scratch, but first I want to check if exist any website with the same name and if exist remove it. But I'm stuck looking the way to delete and create a site using powershell against IIS6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PSdeploy, a powershell module
http://rprieto.github.io/psDeploy/

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you could test a few cmdlets like:

```
    Get-WebApplication | Where-Object{$_.Name -like '*MySiteName*'}
```

And then of course using PSdeploy or MSdeploy modules to deploy your web application